# LG WebOS Emulator

Tags: webos

I spent a day trying to figure out why the LG WebOS Emulator keep getting stuck at the "Booting the Kernel" screen.

The issue was using the 'Oracle VM VirtualBox" configuration screen, the CPU configuration would not update the "LG_webOS_SIGNAGE_Emulator-1.12-windows" config file, instead only update "LG_webOS_SIGNAGE_Emulator" config file.

Once I manually configured the CPU in the "LG_webOS_SIGNAGE_Emulator-1.12-windows" file, the emulator loaded as expected.

Simple config change. I am sure will help anyone else struggling with this issue.

Comment: What is the question exactly? [ask]